How to permanently disable bottom part of the screen
This is my laptop monitor:
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1366/344x768/193+0+0  eDP-1

And I need to resize it to 1366 (or 1360) x 738, positioned at 0x0, so that a 30 pixel-height "stripe" remain permanently "disabled" at the bottom of the screen.
I have tried to set a virtual monitor with xrandr, but cannot figure out how to activate it.

Are you using Xorg? or Wayland? or ...

if Xorg, a suitable hack (having an Xserver in a window inside your xserver) may help? https://superuser.com/a/478861/174998

Yes, I'm using Xorg, but this hack is said to give "reduced graphics performance". I would rather prefer some xrandr-based solution.
